# Setting a default value on MatButtonToggleGroup directive

Tags: angular, angular-material2

In this material 2 snippet, how do we make sure that the button with the `draft` value happens to be the default one? [Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api) mention the `selected` and `checked` directives, but they do not seem to work.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" matInput name="status" [(ngModel)]="status" #field_status="ngModel">
    <mat-button-toggle checked? selected? default? value="draft">
    DRAFT <--how do we set this value to be the default selected/checked one? -->
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="publish">
    PUBLISH
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: try adding a property binding to the selected or the checked, I am not sure it would work but doesn't hurt to try. <mat-button-toggle [checked]="true" [selected]="true" [default]="true" value="draft">

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
public selectedVal: string;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(){
  this.selectedVal ='draft';
} 

public onValChange(val: string) {
  this.selectedVal = val;
}

 <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [value]="selectedVal" (change)="onValChange(group.value)" >
  <mat-button-toggle value="draft">
    Draft
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="publish">
    Publish
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use the variable `status` that is bound via `ngModel` directive.

Something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.status = 'draft';
}
```

Or simply initialize with the value when declaring the field:

```
public status = 'draft';
```